# How to set Monday as start day of the week in Google Sheets date picker

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

How to set Monday as start day of the week in Google Sheets date picker?

I have changed the locale, changed start day of the week in Google Calendar and can't find a way to solve this.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

WEEKNUM(date, [type])

date - The date for which to determine the week number. Must be a reference to a cell containing a date, a function returning a date type, or a number.
type - [ OPTIONAL - default is 1 ] - A number representing the day that a week starts on as well as the system used for determining the first week of the year (1=Sunday, 2=Monday).

Comment: Welcome and sorry. Your answer has nothing to do with the question asked. :(

Answer (score 2):

1. Click File > Spreadsheet settings

[image: Spreadsheet settings]

2. Select United Kingdom or other locale which start week on Monday

[image]
[image]

3. You're all set

[image]

Comment: Not a good answer for me.  Unless you know of a country where both Monday is the first day of the week *and* they use the dollar sign ($) for their currency.  Kind of weird that Google linked all that into "location"

Comment: Not good for me either.  English (UK) is not available to choose from.

Comment: I'm trying to get the opposite effect (Sunday for start of the week) and I've got my local set to the United States but I still get a calendar starting weeks on Monday.

Comment: It has nothing to do with anything related to a specific spreadsheet, because I viewed the same cell in the same spreadsheet from different accounts and the start of the week was different between them.

Comment: It turns out that the link in the above answer (https://myaccount.google.com/language)  is not actually spreadsheet related even though it is in Spreadsheet Settings. I can also add that it does not affect the date and currency notations in the spreadsheets because those are spreadsheet related. I can confirm that both English (United Kingdom) and English (Netherlands) result in Monday going back to its proper position on the left.

Comment: Confirmed that changing locale from English (UK) to English (US) *does* change week start day from Monday to Sunday. You must reload the page in order to see the change!

Comment: @Tharkon That no longer works. Oh my god Google...

Comment: For some reason Google decided weeks start on Sundays in Sweden. They do not. This should be configurable.